# Value entered twice in one vector

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a column with a range 1:5. Many vectors contain the value twice, for example (33) instead of (3) and (11) instead of 1. Is there any code to delete these duplicates and keep one number within a vector?

Thanks a lot

Comment: what's the `class`? `c(1, 11, 2, 3, 33, 4, 5) %% 10`

Comment: Hello rawr and thank you, Class is integer if this is what you mean?

Comment: The columns should only contain (1,2,3,4,5) but due to data entry typos many numbers are repeated in one vector.

Comment: Try `as.numeric(as.character(substr(var, 1, 1)))` where `var` is your column

Comment: Hello Allan and thanks, this gave a new value with one column. The original df remained the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your column is named `y`:

```
substr(y,1,1)
```

Takes from the first digit to the first digit (i.e. only the first) of y (element-wise). But `substr` outputs a `character`, to transform it back to numeric:

```
as.numeric(substr(y,1,1))
```

Comment: Hello Ricardo and many thanks,  this gave a new value with one column. The original df remained the same

Comment: The df is yet not changed :( I tried this way:
'as.numeric(substr(df$column,1,1))'

Comment: Try doing `df$y = as.numeric(substr(df$y,1,1))` (assuming that your dataset is named `df` and the column is named `y`)

Comment: This worked wonder :D many thanks mate!